# Need to provide Pivot report access to ODOO user

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I had installed ODOO 9.0 with Timesheet application and imported few data to create default pivot reports.

Am able to see this when i had logged in as Admin but when i had logged in as an Employee, Reports option in menu itself disabled.

If anybody know please reply and am using ODOO 9.0 community edition.

Screenshots of admin and user login is attached herewith

[image: Admin Login]

[image]

Comment: Am able to do this myself by providing the Manager access to this user under Human Resources option in his profile.

Comment: Is there anyway to get individual timesheet report of an employee inside odoo 9.0?